# lock on sqlcommand object in c#

Tags: c#, locking

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();

lock(cmd)
{

}
```

I am getting a warning:

> locks on a reference type of `SqlCommand`. Replace this with a lock against an object with a strong identity.

How can I remove this warning? I am using multiple functions that use the same kind of functionality.

Comment: I have my code file like this funtion1( ){SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand; lock(cmd){  } } funtion2( ){SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand; lock(cmd){  } } ) and in each function i am getting this warning

Comment: You should think carefully about why you want to do this; RDBMS are already optimised so you rarely have to worry about asking it to do more than one thing at a time. You're creating a bottleneck that may (will) come back to bite you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare a separate object to use for locking:

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
object cmdLock = new object();
```

and:

```
lock (cmdLock)
{
}
```

More info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement